# can't insert form data to database symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I can't insert data form to the database in symfony2 , my codes:

**Controller**

```
public function signupAction(Request $request) {
    $user = new users();
    $form = $this->createForm(new usersType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

    }
```

**form** (userstype)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('email','text',array(
                'label' => 'Due Date',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' =>  'CUSTOM_LABEL_CLASS'
                ),
            ))
            ->add('username' ,'text',array(
                'label' => 'Due Date',
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'class' => 'control-label',
                    'id' => 'password'
                )
            ))
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('location')
            ->add('rememberToken')
            ->add('createdAt')
            ->add('updatedAt')
    ;
}
```

entities (users) :

```
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $location;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="remember_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $rememberToken;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $updatedAt;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set firstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Set lastName
 *
 * @param string $lastName
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * Set location
 *
 * @param string $location
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setLocation($location)
{
    $this->location = $location;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get location
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLocation()
{
    return $this->location;
}

/**
 * Set rememberToken
 *
 * @param string $rememberToken
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setRememberToken($rememberToken)
{
    $this->rememberToken = $rememberToken;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get rememberToken
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->rememberToken;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 *
 * @return users
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting any particular error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have not defined any `data_class` in your FormBuilder therefore the entity will not be persisted.
You can define the `data_class` inside the defaultOptions:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
    ));
}
```

For more information take a look at the [symfony-cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)